# Namespace confusion with multiple modules defined in different js files

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I am struggling to understand an easy way of adding all of my modules to a single namespace.

For example I want a single namespace at the global level, but then my modules to be children of that one namespace

So this is what I have done so far

in the first of my JS files I have done this

```
var MyRootNamespace = window.MyRootNamespace  || (window.MyRootNamespace = {});

(function() {
    MyRootNamespace.EventBus = (function () {

    ...

    })();
})();
```

In another module defined in a different JS file I have

```
(function() {

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        MyRootNamespace.EventBus.publish(...);
    });

})();
```

Trouble is, EventBus is resolving as undefined.  MyRootNamespace exists in the global namespace, but on examination there is no EventBus present in the MyRootNamespace namespace

Whilst I understand the concept of namespaces, I struggle to understand how you create a clean namespace for your application.

Thanks

I just discovered though that if do the following in the module with the reference passed in it all works.

```
(function(BUS) {

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        BUS.EventBus.publish(...);
    });

})(MyRootNamespace.EventBus);
```

Anyone able to explain why?

Comment: try using the prototypal approach, instead of declarative. I.E.  `MyRootNamespace.prototype.EventBus = ...`

Comment: After posting this I had a rare eureka moment where I hope the penny dropped.  I pass in MyRootNamespace.EventBus as a param to the module that needs to use it.  I now no longer get an undefined error and it works.  I would still like to understand why.  I will edit the post to show this

Comment: (function($alias) {
    $alias.foo = function() {
        console.log('bar');
    }
})(this.MyRootNamespace = this.MyRootNamespace || {});

MyRootNamespace.foo();

Comment: I also like that pattern so you're never undefined -- there's at least an empty object.